# What is the connection between data structures and data types?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, type-theory

I have read some books and wikipedia, which seem to give not completely consistent definitions and notations. I try to understand the concepts, regardless of what they are called. Here are what I have figured (please correct me) and would like to ask :

1. a (abstract) data type is a set $D$ of values, together with some
   operations on it (each $n$-ary operation is a mapping $D^n \to D$).
   E.g. The set of all the integers with arithmetic operations on it forms a data type.
2. A data structure seems to be a data type. Or are they the same
   concept? What is the formal definition of a data structure?
3. I have some difficulty in understanding if a "container-like construct" is a data structure or data type, or the set of all of them is. What I mean by a "container-like construct", is some set of values, but with some relation(s) on the set, e.g. a queue, a graph, a stack, an array, a map, .....

   E.g., a queue is a set of values in it, with some ordering on the values according to which value was added earlier than which. Is a queue with a fixed size and fixed elements, as a set of values in it,  a data type or a data structure?  Or do all the queues form a data
   type or a data structure? Are adding and removing elements from a
   queue, which obviously create new queues, viewed as operations on the set of all the queues?

   Similarly, a graph is a set of vertices and has relation between the vertices being the edges. Is a graph with fixed vertices and edges a data type or a
   data structure, or is the set of all the graphs a data type or a
   data structure? Are transformations from a graph to another different graph  considered to be operations on the set of all the graphs? Is searching for a vertex in a graph considered to be an operation on that single graph?

Comment: what books did you read and base this on? You didn't give any specific names.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with your definition of abstract data type.  (A domain of values, together with some operations on that domain.)

I typically use the term *data structure* to refer to *implementation* techniques for data types.  Examples of data *structures* are things like balanced binary trees and hashtables.

For example consider the data *type* `set of integers`, with operations like `union`, `intersection`, `is_member?`, and `insert_member`.

You could implement the data type with at least three different data *structures*, each of which has advantages and disadvantages.  For example, you could implement your set using a balanced binary tree (like a red-black tree, for example).  Each node in the tree represents a member of the set, insertion and membership tests take $O(\log n)$.  Or, if your sets are over a finite (and relatively small) universe of items you could implement it with a `bit array`.  This is an array of $U$ bits (where $U$ is the size of the universe.) Inserting element $i$ just means setting the $i$<sup>th</sup> bit, testing for membership just means testing the $i$<sup>th</sup> bit.  But now intersection (respectively union) requires you to take the binary-`and` (respectively `or`) of $U$ bits, which kind of stinks when you have sets with just a few elements in them.  Similarly with hash table implementations, insertion and testing are nice (on average), but intersection and union can be somewhat more complicated to do efficiently.

Comment: This seems not to define the abstract type "set" per se (or list or whatever), but only "set of <type>" -- and I don't see an obvious+useful+formal way to apply OP's definitions to aggregates: What is the "domain of values" for "set" per se? One could say "any value", but that isn't very revealing, and still fails for "homogeneous set".

Comment: First sentence: An abstract data type is a domain of values, together with some operations on that domain.  The domain of `set`s is all possible "unordered collections of objects," not "any value".  `{a, b}` is a `set`, `{b, a}` is the "same" `set`.  `{a, a}` is _not_ a `set`.

Comment: `list` has a completely different domain: they are ordered sequences of not-necessarily unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simplified view.  For a formal approach, you need to look at
type theory.

**There is no real difference**. Data structures are just standardized
types and type constructors (such as tuple or list), with associated
primitives operations, that are convenient for building other types
with usually a very direct implementation, and are predefined in the
kernel of your programming language.

An abstract data type is defined as an abstract domain D, with its
primitive operations, which is implemented by defining a mapping so
some (more concrete?) type defined with the preexisting constructors.
The primitive operations are also implemented as function using the
primitive operations available for the more concrete
implementation. Then there is an encapsulation mecanism so that the
concrete implementation is hidden, and only the abstract part is usable
in the program.

This abstract data type can be a constructor when its definition
depends on some other yet unspecified type.

Then we can remark that:

- the data structure types defined by the programming languages are
  themselves abstractions: a domain of value and its primitive
  operations. It is seen as concrete because it is mapped in simple
  ways on the computer hardware.
- the definitition of an abstract data type  may well use another
  previouly defined abstract data type for its implementation.

Hence there is no reason to make a difference.

However, the expression "data structure" refers generally to the types
obtained with the primitive types and constructors of the programming
language.

**As a reply to some comments**, and to make things clearer:

I can define a balanced tree ([pick your preferred flavor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)) as an ADT,
call it `Balanced`, implemented with the more elementary types provided
by the language, possibly parameterized by the type of the data it
contains (which would rather make it an ADT constructor, to use my
informal terminology).  Then I can used this ADT `Balanced` to build another ADT
called `Set` for sets, as suggested in the answer of Wandering
Logic. Then I can use the ADT `Set` to implement some other ADT `XXX`.

Note that I could be more specific and actually call my ADT `Red-Black`,
with a [corresponding implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), if I want to suggest that it will
have exactly all the properties of red-black trees. It will
nevertheless be an ADT, since the program will be allowed to use only
the given primitives, without being allowed to fiddle with the
pointers of the implementation at the risk of bugging the structure.

Then people may consider that data-structures are what is used for
implementation, while ADTs are the abstraction that is built with the
data structure. I will not fight it as this is terminology, and it
does not really matter to me (see further comments below). But, then,
I will point out that `Balanced`, or `Set`, are clearly ADTs when
being defined, but become data structures when looked at from the
point of view of the other ADTs they are used to implement.

*This only confirms what I said. They are the same.*

I know "[we eat *beef* and *pork* rather than *cow* and *pig*](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2008/why-do-we-eat-beef-and-pork-rather-than-cow-and-pig)", but
these four names cover only two species, and the difference is only in
the use made of the animal. Whether an ADT is *pork* or *pig* may be
convenient terminology, may indicate a difference in intent, or a difference of perspective, but not a
difference in substance.

Another issue raised in that context is that of **complexity**, as if it
mattered more when looking at data structure, at implementation.

An immediate consequence of what I just said is that there cannot be
any difference on that basis. When I implement the ADT `Balanced`, I am
of course very careful to have a good implementation. And the
complexity characteristics of the functions associated with that ADT
(insertion, deletion, traversal, ...)  are of course part of the
specification, though that is usually implicit in the program, as well
as other interesting properties of the abstraction (quite often). Then
I can rely on the complexity of the `Balanced` primitives to analyse the
complexity of whatever is implemented using `Balanced`.

When I use the ADT `Balanced` as data structure to implement the ADT
`Set`, I will again be careful to get good complexity of its primitive
operations (such as union or intersection of `Set` values) which will be
(possibly implicitely) part of the Set interface specification. So,
when I analyse the complexity of the ADT `XXX`, I can simply rely on what
I know of the complexity of `Set`.

And this is very much what we do when studying the complexity of
intricate algorithms.  We rely on existing, well analysed constructs,
and seldom look into the way they were themselves designed and
analyzed. This is the essence of abstraction, and it is only the classical way of doing Mathematics. When we
use a theorem, we do not have to think about its proof (Thanks to
Curry and Howard for their support in this discussion).

Now I gave my view of the use of the terminology. It may be outdated,
I do not know. But I would not worry a second about it since the two
expression denote the same substance anyway. The difference, if any,
is in the way you want to look at that substance. My own perception is
that the only concrete difference is between the fact that original
data types of the language are hard-coded by the compiler and have to
be taken as they are, while all others, user or library defined abstract data
types, can be re-implemented if need be. As I perceive that as the only
significant difference, I rather use the extra word data structure to
identify that. It may be that there is a different consensus in some
communities, actually shared by the [answer of Wandering Logic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/what-is-the-connection-between-data-structures-and-data-types/29128#29128).
A justification for it is that people could use the implementation
based on other types without ever abstracting it, which would support
the idea of having a specific name for it (I often just use the word
*implementation*).

Then, just to make things a bit more confused, the Wikipedia page for
*[Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)* talks also of *Abstract Data Structure*, wich a link
to ... *[Abstract Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)*.

Somehow, I strongly doubt there is an official unified terminology for all
this. Except probably when giving formal definitions using type theory.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "For a formal approach, you need to look at type theory." Nice said. I am looking for some references that introduce data structures from math or type theory. Do you have recommendations? (2) Is a queue a data structure/type, or the set of all queues a data structure/type. This is part of the third part of my post.

Comment: @Tim For me, a queue is an ADT constructor, which produces an ADT when you specify
the type of its elements. Then integer-queue is an ADT, which is the
*type* (read *set* if you wish) of all queues of integers. A queue has
nothing specific in it: for all I know there is a deamon there
answering my queries colleting input and handing out output. Whether
queue operations change the queue or create a new one is a matter of
choice when you implement it. In a functional language, it should be
the latter (but the compiler can optimize that). I am not
the best person to recommend a type theory book.

Comment: (1) not actually all about type thoery, but data structures from modeling types point of view. (2) Is `template` in C++ also an ADT constructor? (3) all the integer-queues form an ADT, regardless of the lengths of the queues, which can be different from each other in the ADT?

Comment: (1) I have not been teaching for too long, and I learned it as it was
invented. (2) I always refused to learn C++ to preserve my sanity. (3)
In principle, the length of the queue should not matter. Then there is
reality, which is handled in a good programming language with an
exception. But actually, the choice of the abstraction definition is
whatever the designer chooses. Taste and experience do matter.

Comment: "I always refused to learn C++ to preserve my sanity." what programming languages (do you recommend which) can preserve your (and our) sanity? I would like to preserve my sanity too!

Comment: @Tim Choosing a language depends much on the problem and on your own taste and style. But I generally like a language with a fairly simple kernel (I mean excluding the huge library collections we now get). I like concepts that make logical sense and help me organize thing. I am more concerned with logic than implementation. C++ happens to be very big and to be too much concerned with implementation first (trying to explain in a nutshell). Languages I used are Fortran, Pascal, ML, Lisp, Perl, Python, and some others you probably would not know. I studied some others.

Comment: With data structures, the runtime performance (time and space complexity) of the operations is important. What is more, a data structure is a particular way to achieve particular performance bounds for these operations.  So a data structure is not an abstract data type, but an implementation of an abstract data type.

Comment: Informally, could we just say that a data type is a [transparent reference][1] to the prototype or abstraction of a data structure? It seems to me that this would neatly, succinctly capture what a programmer needs to know.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/210835/2593553

Comment: @reinierpost First, thank you for explaining your downvote (I assume
it was you). I wrote a complement to my answer which may hopefully
answer your comment, at least regarding complexity issues.  Regarding
the terminology, You will notice that the OP says that its use is
rather inconsistant. Wandering Logic says in his answer "I typically
use the term data structure to refer ...", which is not too assertive
regarding the universality of that use. I am slightly more assertive
(too much?), I think without excess. What really matters is to make clear what is
meant when writing about it.